# How to convert Windows-based ISO for Mac OS X Installation DVD?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, windows, iso

I made an ISO image from Mac OS X Snow Leopard Installation DVD using PowerISO on Windows machine. The ISO file size is 7.6GB, but when I mount the ISO using PowerISO, what I can see is only the files for Windows (900+MB). How can I convert it back to Mac format ISO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty normal to see only the files for windows, when you are mounting the ISO image on a windows!

Even if you have inserted a MAC OS Installation DVD (physical) into tray and openned it in a windows machine, you would have seen only the Windows files and not the MAC files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the contents of the DVD from the cmd prompt under Windows?  I suspect the explorer is hiding the Mac contents.

In the same vein, put the DVD in a Mac and examine it there for the Mac files.